# Using Typeahead.js with Bootstrap 3 in xpages not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, lotus-domino, typeahead.js

I am trying to use the typeahead.js functionality with bootstrap 3 in an Xpage.

I have included the Bootstrap 3 files, jQuery2.4.3  and typeahead.js in the database( webContent) and included them as resources along with the input field/Editbox and assigned it with the class of 'typeahead'.

I am using an example from a response by [Mark Leusink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1177870/mark-leusink) to another separate issue [Xpages: TypeAhead with Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625225/xpages-typeahead-with-twitter-bootstrap-loading-a-ssjs-array-into-the-value-l).

See my Xpage code below:

```
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" >
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:styleSheet
            href="/bootstrap/css/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css">
        </xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:script src="/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:script src="/jquery/x$.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
        <xp:script src="/typeahead/typeahead.bundle.js"
            clientSide="true">
        </xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("typeaheadOptions", toJson(["Alabama", "Alaska"]));}]]>
    </xp:this.beforePageLoad>

    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" autocomplete="off"
        styleClass="typeahead tt-query">

    </xp:inputText>

    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[var value = #{viewScope.typeaheadOptions};
x$('inputText1').typeahead({source: value });

    ]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```

When I type in the input field nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any error messages from the client side javascript console?

Comment: My guess is that typeahead.js uses AMD. See this answer on how to disable AMD: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26339718/785061

Comment: Thanks for the response @PerHenrikLausten I have now disabled the AMD in jquery.js and in the typeahead.js  however I still don't get any result.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLeedy. I am not getting any error msgs - only the "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." for the dojo.js. Is this my issue??

Comment: I don't believe that's your issue.  I see those messages on my stuff.

Comment: I have the same problem. No usual tricks seem to help and there is no error message in the client console to help with troubleshooting. Will keep investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have these Items working now. I beleive it was down to the way I modified the JS files to disable the AMD loader. When I repeated the processes of modifying the originals and reloaded and it worked. Also I now agree with david and the warning message 'Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread can be ignored